# How to stream files to FFmpeg?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, http, remote, pipe

I am trying to create a video (MP4) from a bunch of images (JPEG). I am using FFmpeg for that. I know that I can pipe the contents of the images if they’re on the same server:

```
cat *.jpg | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -r 1/5 -c:v ...
```

But how do I stream the images from a HTTP/HTTPS location?